# Spring management extension like JMX

Tags: java, spring, jmx

Looking for a management like JMX for spring beans. i wanted to load all the spring beans to the container and using a simple swing gui/jgraphs to show the bean dependencies/details etc

Likewise viewing the spring dependency one can also create a dependency from the ui.

please suggest any open source tool or point me to a code snippet.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: How about Spring Insight? http://www.springsource.org/insight